# Inconsistent ability to adjust blocks using Twig due to naming conventions (underscores, etc)

Tags: twig, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am having difficulties getting my Drupal blocks and regions to interact with my Twig Template Files. I suspect some of it may be syntax but a lot of it seems to be understanding what to name my Twig files.

For instance in my custom block library I have an "Eyebrow Text and Heading" custom block. This has form fields of "field_eyebrow_text" and "field_heading". The machine name for this custom block is "eyebrow_text_and_heading"...

So I created a folder named "eyebrow-text-and-heading" in my template folder and then I named the twig file for this block: block--eyebrow-text-and-heading.html.twig

Inside this file:

```
{% if content %}
<h5 class="eyebrow">{{content.field_eyebrow_text}}</h5>
<h2 class="eyebrow-heading">{{content.field_heading}}</h2>
{% endif %}
```

I have this set up in a block region named "Light blue", machine name "light_blue". Inside region--light-blue.html.twig I have:

```
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}
{% if content %}

  <div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    <div class="container-fuid">
      <div class="container">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

I also have a "field--block-content--light-blue.html.twig" which has the following code:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

None of this code is showing up anywhere on the site.

Simply put, I want it so that every time I create a "Eyebrow Text and Heading" custom block which the user fills out the two fields, that it will have the same HTML structure that I have in block--eyebrow-text-and-heading.html.twig ... at this point, if I put the code into the Light Blue region it just surrounds it with divs. There is no code. The light blue region code is not showing up either. Can someone explain to me how to name these twig files?

I have shown what I tried above...

I am just expecting this template code to get picked up by Drupal like some of my other blogs but I feel like I am naming things wrong with a naming convention.

TY